# Como pegar a url de formulários diferentes e validar via javascript

Tags: javascript, formulário

Atualmente estou fazendo assim e toda vez que submito o form o alerta retorna erro mesmo com os campos preenchidos corretamente

```js
$('.form-ajax').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $('#formnews');

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            async: true,
            data: form.serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    swal('Bom trabalho!', 'Sua inscrição foi efetuada com sucesso!', 'success');
                    $('#formnews').val('');
                } else {
                    swal('Alguma coisa errada', result.message, 'warning');
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                swal('Erro!', 'Ocorreu um erro', 'error');
            }
        })
    });
```

```html
<form action="{{ route('newsletter.post.ajax') }}" method="POST" id="formnews">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="field has-addons">
                        <div class="control is-expanded has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <p class="control is-expanded has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                                    <input id="email_newsletter" type="email_newsletter" class="input" name="email_newsletter" value="{{ old('email_newsletter') }}" placeholder="Seu melhor email" required>
                                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                             <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control">
                            <button type="submit" class="button is-warning">
                                Cadastrar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, sem o código completo posso apenas fazer suposições, mas de início acho que você o problema pode ser no teste if (result.success).

Como você valida via código os campos? Para que result seja igual a TRUE você deverá determinar alguns testes, porém, os mesmos não parecem ocorrer em momento algum.

Por isso, acho que o código sempre retornará erro mesmo com os campos preenchidos corretamente.

Comment: Quando uso apenas id ele valida normalmente, o problema é que eu tenho outros formularios na pagina e não posso usar o mesmo id para validar então tentei usar classe mas não funciona

Comment: Desculpe, mas não entendi em que ponto o uso ou não do mesmo Id interferiria com o problema da validação do result. Talvez o problema seja outro. Uma boa prática é sempre criar diferentes Id para cada formulários. Ajudaria muito se disponibliizasse mais trechos do seu código-fonte.

Comment: <form name="formcontato" class="form-horizontal form-ajax" method="POST" action="{{ route('page.student.post') }}">

Comment: tenho dois formularios um em cada pagina porem preciso passar eles por uma validação via java script e retornar um amensagem com switalert mais como faço que o mesmo java script valide dois formularios diferentes

Comment: <form action="{{ route('newsletter.post.ajax') }}" method="POST" id="formnews"> esse codigo é do segundo form

Comment: Ok, mas onde acontece a validação dos campos?

Comment: eu tinha visto uma maneira de envez de pegar id ou classe pegar a url da pagina assim eu poderia usar validar o formulario basedo na sua url e não no sua id

Comment: a validação acontece no proprio formulario

Comment: Fiz algumas pesquisa mas infelizmente não consegui encontrar nada relevante. Francamente, acho incomum o fato de não optar pelo uso do Id, já que isso facilitaria enormemente o trabalho. Sinto não poder ajudar além disso.

Comment: achei o problema era por id mesmo o problema era a logica da minha controller que estava errada